# Links to animated background image landing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a landing page with 8 background images using a javascript to animate it fading in/out and I'd like to add links to each of the images when they appear. Is this possible?

If so, what do I need to change into the code, I tried by adding (a) at the (ul) but didn't work.

Thank you,

Max

```js
/* Modernizr 2.0.6 (Custom Build) | MIT & BSD
 * Build: http://www.modernizr.com/download/#-cssanimations-iepp-cssclasses-testprop-testallprops-domprefixes-load
 */
;window.Modernizr=function(a,b,c){function A(a,b){var c=a.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+a.substr(1),d=(a+" "+n.join(c+" ")+c).split(" ");return z(d,b)}function z(a,b){for(var d in a)if(k[a[d]]!==c)return b=="pfx"?a[d]:!0;return!1}function y(a,b){return!!~(""+a).indexOf(b)}function x(a,b){return typeof a===b}function w(a,b){return v(prefixes.join(a+";")+(b||""))}function v(a){k.cssText=a}var d="2.0.6",e={},f=!0,g=b.documentElement,h=b.head||b.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],i="modernizr",j=b.createElement(i),k=j.style,l,m=Object.prototype.toString,n="Webkit Moz O ms Khtml".split(" "),o={},p={},q={},r=[],s,t={}.hasOwnProperty,u;!x(t,c)&&!x(t.call,c)?u=function(a,b){return t.call(a,b)}:u=function(a,b){return b in a&&x(a.constructor.prototype[b],c)},o.cssanimations=function(){return A("animationName")};for(var B in o)u(o,B)&&(s=B.toLowerCase(),e[s]=o[B](),r.push((e[s]?"":"no-")+s));v(""),j=l=null,a.attachEvent&&function(){var a=b.createElement("div");a.innerHTML="<elem></elem>";return a.childNodes.length!==1}()&&function(a,b){function s(a){var b=-1;while(++b<g)a.createElement(f[b])}a.iepp=a.iepp||{};var d=a.iepp,e=d.html5elements||"abbr|article|aside|audio|canvas|datalist|details|figcaption|figure|footer|header|hgroup|mark|meter|nav|output|progress|section|summary|time|video",f=e.split("|"),g=f.length,h=new RegExp("(^|\\s)("+e+")","gi"),i=new RegExp("<(/*)("+e+")","gi"),j=/^\s*[\{\}]\s*$/,k=new RegExp("(^|[^\\n]*?\\s)("+e+")([^\\n]*)({[\\n\\w\\W]*?})","gi"),l=b.createDocumentFragment(),m=b.documentElement,n=m.firstChild,o=b.createElement("body"),p=b.createElement("style"),q=/print|all/,r;d.getCSS=function(a,b){if(a+""===c)return"";var e=-1,f=a.length,g,h=[];while(++e<f){g=a[e];if(g.disabled)continue;b=g.media||b,q.test(b)&&h.push(d.getCSS(g.imports,b),g.cssText),b="all"}return h.join("")},d.parseCSS=function(a){var b=[],c;while((c=k.exec(a))!=null)b.push(((j.exec(c[1])?"\n":c[1])+c[2]+c[3]).replace(h,"$1.iepp_$2")+c[4]);return b.join("\n")},d.writeHTML=function(){var a=-1;r=r||b.body;while(++a<g){var c=b.getElementsByTagName(f[a]),d=c.length,e=-1;while(++e<d)c[e].className.indexOf("iepp_")<0&&(c[e].className+=" iepp_"+f[a])}l.appendChild(r),m.appendChild(o),o.className=r.className,o.id=r.id,o.innerHTML=r.innerHTML.replace(i,"<$1font")},d._beforePrint=function(){p.styleSheet.cssText=d.parseCSS(d.getCSS(b.styleSheets,"all")),d.writeHTML()},d.restoreHTML=function(){o.innerHTML="",m.removeChild(o),m.appendChild(r)},d._afterPrint=function(){d.restoreHTML(),p.styleSheet.cssText=""},s(b),s(l);d.disablePP||(n.insertBefore(p,n.firstChild),p.media="print",p.className="iepp-printshim",a.attachEvent("onbeforeprint",d._beforePrint),a.attachEvent("onafterprint",d._afterPrint))}(a,b),e._version=d,e._domPrefixes=n,e.testProp=function(a){return z([a])},e.testAllProps=A,g.className=g.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/,"")+(f?" js "+r.join(" "):"");return e}(this,this.document),function(a,b,c){function k(a){return!a||a=="loaded"||a=="complete"}function j(){var a=1,b=-1;while(p.length- ++b)if(p[b].s&&!(a=p[b].r))break;a&&g()}function i(a){var c=b.createElement("script"),d;c.src=a.s,c.onreadystatechange=c.onload=function(){!d&&k(c.readyState)&&(d=1,j(),c.onload=c.onreadystatechange=null)},m(function(){d||(d=1,j())},H.errorTimeout),a.e?c.onload():n.parentNode.insertBefore(c,n)}function h(a){var c=b.createElement("link"),d;c.href=a.s,c.rel="stylesheet",c.type="text/css";if(!a.e&&(w||r)){var e=function(a){m(function(){if(!d)try{a.sheet.cssRules.length?(d=1,j()):e(a)}catch(b){b.code==1e3||b.message=="security"||b.message=="denied"?(d=1,m(function(){j()},0)):e(a)}},0)};e(c)}else c.onload=function(){d||(d=1,m(function(){j()},0))},a.e&&c.onload();m(function(){d||(d=1,j())},H.errorTimeout),!a.e&&n.parentNode.insertBefore(c,n)}function g(){var a=p.shift();q=1,a?a.t?m(function(){a.t=="c"?h(a):i(a)},0):(a(),j()):q=0}function f(a,c,d,e,f,h){function i(){!o&&k(l.readyState)&&(r.r=o=1,!q&&j(),l.onload=l.onreadystatechange=null,m(function(){u.removeChild(l)},0))}var l=b.createElement(a),o=0,r={t:d,s:c,e:h};l.src=l.data=c,!s&&(l.style.display="none"),l.width=l.height="0",a!="object"&&(l.type=d),l.onload=l.onreadystatechange=i,a=="img"?l.onerror=i:a=="script"&&(l.onerror=function(){r.e=r.r=1,g()}),p.splice(e,0,r),u.insertBefore(l,s?null:n),m(function(){o||(u.removeChild(l),r.r=r.e=o=1,j())},H.errorTimeout)}function e(a,b,c){var d=b=="c"?z:y;q=0,b=b||"j",C(a)?f(d,a,b,this.i++,l,c):(p.splice(this.i++,0,a),p.length==1&&g());return this}function d(){var a=H;a.loader={load:e,i:0};return a}var l=b.documentElement,m=a.setTimeout,n=b.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],o={}.toString,p=[],q=0,r="MozAppearance"in l.style,s=r&&!!b.createRange().compareNode,t=r&&!s,u=s?l:n.parentNode,v=a.opera&&o.call(a.opera)=="[object Opera]",w="webkitAppearance"in l.style,x=w&&"async"in b.createElement("script"),y=r?"object":v||x?"img":"script",z=w?"img":y,A=Array.isArray||function(a){return o.call(a)=="[object Array]"},B=function(a){return Object(a)===a},C=function(a){return typeof a=="string"},D=function(a){return o.call(a)=="[object Function]"},E=[],F={},G,H;H=function(a){function f(a){var b=a.split("!"),c=E.length,d=b.pop(),e=b.length,f={url:d,origUrl:d,prefixes:b},g,h;for(h=0;h<e;h++)g=F[b[h]],g&&(f=g(f));for(h=0;h<c;h++)f=E[h](f);return f}function e(a,b,e,g,h){var i=f(a),j=i.autoCallback;if(!i.bypass){b&&(b=D(b)?b:b[a]||b[g]||b[a.split("/").pop().split("?")[0]]);if(i.instead)return i.instead(a,b,e,g,h);e.load(i.url,i.forceCSS||!i.forceJS&&/css$/.test(i.url)?"c":c,i.noexec),(D(b)||D(j))&&e.load(function(){d(),b&&b(i.origUrl,h,g),j&&j(i.origUrl,h,g)})}}function b(a,b){function c(a){if(C(a))e(a,h,b,0,d);else if(B(a))for(i in a)a.hasOwnProperty(i)&&e(a[i],h,b,i,d)}var d=!!a.test,f=d?a.yep:a.nope,g=a.load||a.both,h=a.callback,i;c(f),c(g),a.complete&&b.load(a.complete)}var g,h,i=this.yepnope.loader;if(C(a))e(a,0,i,0);else if(A(a))for(g=0;g<a.length;g++)h=a[g],C(h)?e(h,0,i,0):A(h)?H(h):B(h)&&b(h,i);else B(a)&&b(a,i)},H.addPrefix=function(a,b){F[a]=b},H.addFilter=function(a){E.push(a)},H.errorTimeout=1e4,b.readyState==null&&b.addEventListener&&(b.readyState="loading",b.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",G=function(){b.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",G,0),b.readyState="complete"},0)),a.yepnope=d()}(this,this.document),Modernizr.load=function(){yepnope.apply(window,[].slice.call(arguments,0))};
```

```css
.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
}
.cb-slideshow:after {
  content: '';
  background: transparent;
}
.cb-slideshow li span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  color: transparent;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  -moz-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  -o-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
.cb-slideshow li div {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 42s linear infinite 0s;
  -moz-animation: titleAnimation 42s linear infinite 0s;
  -o-animation: titleAnimation 42s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: titleAnimation 42s linear infinite 0s;
  animation: titleAnimation 42s linear infinite 0s;
}
.cb-slideshow li div h3 {
  font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 240px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 200px;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span {
  background-image: url(../images/1.jpg)
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
  background-image: url(../images/2.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -o-animation-delay: 6s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span {
  background-image: url(../images/3.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  -o-animation-delay: 12s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span {
  background-image: url(../images/4.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
  -o-animation-delay: 18s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
  animation-delay: 18s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) span {
  background-image: url(../images/5.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
  -o-animation-delay: 24s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
  animation-delay: 24s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span {
  background-image: url(../images/6.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
  -o-animation-delay: 30s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
  animation-delay: 30s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(7) span {
  background-image: url(../images/7.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 36s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 36s;
  -o-animation-delay: 36s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 36s;
  animation-delay: 36s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(8) span {
  background-image: url(../images/8.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 42s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 42s;
  -o-animation-delay: 42s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 42s;
  animation-delay: 42s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) div {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -o-animation-delay: 6s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) div {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  -o-animation-delay: 12s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) div {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
  -o-animation-delay: 18s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
  animation-delay: 18s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) div {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
  -o-animation-delay: 24s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
  animation-delay: 24s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) div {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
  -o-animation-delay: 30s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
  animation-delay: 30s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(7) div {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 36s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 36s;
  -o-animation-delay: 36s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 36s;
  animation-delay: 36s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(8) div {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 42s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 42s;
  -o-animation-delay: 42s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 42s;
  animation-delay: 42s;
}
/* Animation for the slideshow images */

@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@-o-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
/* Animation for the title */

@-webkit-keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  19% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  19% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@-o-keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  19% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  19% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  19% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
/* Show at least something when animations not supported */

.no-cssanimations .cb-slideshow li span {
  opacity: 1;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1140px) {
  .cb-slideshow li div h3 {
    font-size: 140px
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .cb-slideshow li div h3 {
    font-size: 80px
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Oikos Creative Lab / Communication Design</title>

  <meta name="description" content="Oikos é un’agenzia di comunicazione e design che offre soluzioni strategiche cross media.">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/css/demo.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/css/style1.css" />

  <style type="text/css">
    #dati {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 2%;
      color: #FFFDFD;
      font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      text-align: left;
      font-size: small;
      height: 20px;
      padding-top: 0px;
      padding-right: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      padding-left: 0px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      width: 40%;
    }
    #book {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 2%;
      color: #FFFDFD;
      font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      text-align: left;
      font-size: small;
      height: 0x;
      padding-top: 0px;
      padding-right: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      padding-left: 0px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      width: 175px;
    }
    #footer {
      float: right;
      margin-right: 2%;
      color: #FFFDFD;
      font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      text-align: right;
      font-size: small;
      height: 20px;
      width: 250px;
      padding-top: 0px;
      padding-right: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      padding-left: 0px;
      margin-top: 5px;
    }
    .contenitore {
      background-color: #000000;
      height: 60px;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      z-index: 9999;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
    .contenitore #footer a {
      color: #808080;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .contenitore #footer a:hover {
      color: #FFFFFF;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/js/modernizr.custom.86080.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

  <ul class="cb-slideshow">
    <li><span>Image 01</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>Image 02</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>Image 03</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>Image 04</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>Image 05</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>Image 06</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>Image 07</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>Image 08</span>
    </li>

  </ul>
  <div class="clr"></div>
  <div class="contenitore">
    <div id="dati">oikos creative lab s.r.l. / via volturno 16 20900 monza mb it
      <br>t.+39 0392301644 / <a href="mailto:info@oikoscreativelab.com">info@oikoscreativelab.com</a>
    </div>

    <div id="book">download our porfolio
      <img src="CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/images/acro_ico.png" width="30" height="34" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div id="footer">c.f. p.iva 09201110963 / r.i. MB-1903327
      <br>capitale sociale: € 10.000,00 i.v.</div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```